# $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

There has been a [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334202/c-cx-is-dense-in-c-0x) discussing why $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ but I would like to know if we can even extend this to saying that $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R})?$

Does anybody know if this is possible??

Comment: Are you familiar with convolutions?

Comment: I am familiar with convolutions, but normally I only know their applications for $L^p$ with $p<\infty$

Comment: @DanielFischer ah thanks, you are right, it also works in this case, even with the standard mollifier.